# Pytest using a fixture to return value instead of function location

Tags: unit-testing, pytest

I want to perform `pytest` for the `tenth_standard` method inside `HighSchool` class:

```
Class HighSchool():
    ...

    def tenth_standard(self):
        return f"I-am-studying-in-{self.school}-at-{self.country}"
```

I want to use `@pytest.fixture` and `@pytest.mark.parametrize` to perform the pytest and my code is as below:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def expected(request):
    return f"I-am-studying-in-{school}-at-{country}"

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def school(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def country(request):
    return request.param





@pytest.mark.parametrize("school", ["abcd", "efgh"], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("country", ["India", "Japan"], indirect=True)

def test_tenthstandard(school, country, expected):

    b = HighSchool(school=school, country=country)
    assert expected == b.tenth_standard()
```

When I run this, I get an `AssertionError` as below:

`AssertionError: assert ('I-am-studying-in-<function school at 0x7f6b858a63a0>-at-<function country at '0x7f6b858a6280>) == 'I-am-studying-in-abcd-at-India'`

I want to fix the `expected fixture` to return the values instead of `function at XXX location`. Could someone help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `expected` fixture is not taking the parameters from the other fixtures, but just the fixture function, which is of course not what you want. You can just "derive" the `expected` fixture from the other fixtures, so it will be automatically parametrized with the same parameters:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def school(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def country(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def expected(school, country):
    return f"I-am-studying-in-{school}-at-{country}"

@pytest.mark.parametrize("school", ["abcd", "efgh"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("country", ["India", "Japan"])
def test_tenthstandard(school, country, expected):
    b = HighSchool(school=school, country=country)
    assert expected == b.tenth_standard()
```

Note that it this case you can even skip the `indirect=True` part, as the `expected` fixture will already get the correct values.

As a side note: It is usually not a good idea to duplicate the application logic in the test, as is done here. This way bugs can easily propagate to the tests and not be found.
(though in this case it may only be due to a dumbed down example)

Comment: regarding "As a side note" - how would you suggest doing a pytest for this kind of tests to avoid duplication of application logic?

Comment: Usually you make tests dumb, e.g. without any logic, so you would use the actual expected string as an expected parameter, instead of "calculating" it. In your case, this would mean a single `parametrize` with 3 parameters. This is more important for more complicated use cases, of course.

Comment: A doubt here: The fixture functions `school` and `country` are doing the same thing. Can we generalise the fixture function and use it for both `school` and `country`?